# Regular Expression Issue C# or Java

Tags: java, c#, regex, loadrunner, vugen

I have a string of text that I am trying to break into pieces in Loadrunner
Here are two possible combinations of text

```
309-95-90570-0243-023-0030

222-627-90570-0365-042-0031
```

I need to be able to break each section that is inside of the "`-`" into separate variables.

For Example the variables need to be

First Variable - `309` from the first set and `222` from the second set

It gets tricky here for the second variable bc in the first example it contains two characters where in the second example it contains three characters.

Second Variable - `95` from the first set and `627` from the second set

Third Variable - `90570` from the first set and `90570` from the second set

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: First you need to decide on a language and then you need to show some effort on your own. We are not here to do your work for you, but rather to help out with specific issues you are stumped on yourself.

Comment: @KingofMasses, how could this possibly be a duplicate of something concerning email addresses?

Comment: LoadRunner is a C language product, so you may want a solution in C.  There are a number of possible solutions, including the use of strtok() with the '-' as a token. strstr() could be used to locate the first instance of the '-' and then strncpy to copy the first n characters to another string.  You can also play move the pointer on the original string in a recursive fashion &pointerstringvariablename[offset] to get the last portion of the string beginning at the offset and reuse strstr() and strncpy().  C is a foundation class skill for the use of LoadRunner, as is Java for JMETER

Answer (score 0):

Simply use split function. Example:

```
String foo = "309-95-90570-0243-023-0030";
String[] bar = foo.split("-"); 
for (String s : bar) {
     System.out.println(s);
}
```

Also you could always make values from string to int with     `Integer.parseInt(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will do the work.

```
    public static List<List<string>> GetSplitedValues(IList<string> _inputList )
    {

        string[] splitwords = _inputList[0].Split('-');
        List<string>[] _ouputList = new List<string>[splitwords.Length];
        for(int i=0;i<_ouputList.Length;i++)
        {
            _ouputList[i]=new List<string>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _inputList.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] _splitwords = _inputList[i].Split('-');
            for (int j = 0; j < splitwords.Length; j++)
            {
                _ouputList[j].Add(_splitwords[j]);
            }
        }
        List<List<string> >_temp= new List<List<string>>();
        _temp.AddRange(_ouputList);
        return _temp;



    }
```

and you can test using these lines

```
 List<string> _a=new List<string>();
            _a.Add("222-627-90570-0365-042-0031");
            _a.Add("309-95-90570-0243-023-0030");
            List<List<string>> _o = GetSplitedValues(_a);
            foreach (var list in _o)
            {
                foreach (var str in list)
                {
                    Console.Write(str);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```